# Operation of 'git pull' unaffected by .gitignore_global file

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I have two local git repositories corresponding to a remote repository named `quest`. One local repository is on a Windows machine on which I run git commands via Cygwin. The other is on a Linux system.

The specific examples listed below refer to the latter case.

I have a `.gitconfig` file in my home directory (`/hhome/jj`) with an entry

```
[core]
  excludesfile = /hhome/jj/.gitignore_global
```

that points to a global `.gitignore` file, also in my home directory.

I am trying to set up git to ignore everything in the `matlab_stuff` subdirectory of this git repository, now and forever. The full path to this subdirectory is `/hhome/jj/gitroot/quest/matlab_stuff`. I had thought I would be able to accomplish this by putting one or the other of the following lines

```
matlab_stuff/
/hhome/jj/gitroot/quest/matlab_stuff/
```

in `~/.gitignore_global`, but it's not working

I know that this is not sufficient to make git ignore files that it is already tracking. To eliminate those I used something like

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file-name>
```

on each file in the `matlab_stuff` subdirectory. Then I deleted the whole `/hhome/jj/gitroot/quest/matlab_stuff` subdirectory.

Everything seemed fine. I can make changes to other files, commit them, and push them without messing up the global repository for other users.

However, as soon as I do a 'git pull' after someone else has pushed new files to `matlab_stuff`, that subdirectory gets recreated and the new files are put in, which is exactly what I was hoping to avoid.

Running `git config --global -l` shows the correct `core.excludesfile` entry so it's not as if git is unaware of the global `.gitignore` file.

As I say, this not working as expected on two similarly configured local git repositories.

Why isn't this working and/or how can I fix it?

Comment: No.  `git update-index` doesn't change the status of the MATLAB files in the repo, it is more of a local thing.  If those MATLAB files are already in the repo, you will need to `git rm --cached` those files, then push the deletion to the repo.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. I personally don't want any matlab stuff in my local copy of the git repository, but I don't want to make any changes to the remote repository. Other users want the matlab files. In other words, I can't push my preferences to the remote repository.

Comment: You can't do this, the files are either in the repo or they're not.  You should find an agreement with everyone regarding this.  Workarounds will be ugly and prone to error.

Comment: Here again, I'm not trying to change the remote repo and I don't think it is or should be required. Global .gitignore functionality is provided so I can make my own choices about things I want to ignore. This is how it is described in many places (e.g., [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)).

Answer (score 3):

First, `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by a second command, usually `git merge` (though you can tell it to do `git rebase` instead).  All the real action comes about because of the second command: The `git fetch` step is entirely safe and can be used at any time: it merely obtains *new* commits from some other Git and adds them to your repository, where you can do whatever you want with them later.  It has no effect on any existing checked-out stuff.

Next, we can point out that `.gitignore` never affects `git merge` (nor `git rebase`).  Put this together with the first point, and you will see that `.gitignore` never affects `git pull`.

#### Commits, the index, and the work-tree

To understand what's really going on, though, we have to get into the difference between these three things, in Git:

- Commits.

  Commits are Git's [*raison d'être*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre).  Each commit saves a complete snapshot of a source tree, plus some metadata: an author (name, email, and time-stamp); a committer (the same three things, usually with the same values); the hash IDs of some *parent* commit or commits, so that there will be a history of commits; and a log message, usually written by the committer (although *merge commits* often have auto-generated boring messages).

  The saved snapshot in a commit consists of a *tree* of files and sub-directories (sub-trees, in Git-ese) that in turn contain more files and/or sub-sub-directories, and so on.  Each file is stored in a compressed internal format, using a funny (hashed) name, that only makes sense to Git itself.  Therefore, you also have ...
- The *work-tree*.  The work-tree is where Git lets you work with your files.  Here, they have the ordinary format the computer itself expects, so that you can edit them and change them and so on.  There is normally exactly one work-tree for every repository.<sup>1</sup>

  This might be enough, and other version control systems do in fact stop here, but Git also provides for you—and *forces* you to understand—one more part, which is ...
- The *index*.  The index is pretty mysterious at first (and even for hard core Git users, it can still be kind of mysterious).  It has several other names as well: the *staging area*, which is a pretty good name—as we will see in a moment—and also the *cache*, which is more about how it gets used: the cache aspect of the index is what gives Git its great speed advantage over many other version control systems.

  The main thing to know about the index, though, is that it's *where you build the next commit you will make.*  It starts out "equal to" some existing commit.  We just noted that each commit is a complete snapshot of your source.  The way it *got there* was by being saved out of an index.  When you first clone a repository and check out a commit, Git copies the commit *into* your index: so your index matches the commit.

  If all you ever do is check out commits, each new `git checkout` makes the index match the new commit.  Your index and your current commit will just always match.  Moreover, if you never touch your work-tree either, your index and work-tree will *also* always match.

  Like the work-tree, there is normally exactly one index.  The index records information *about* what's in the work-tree (that's its cache aspect), as well as matching up to the commit.  Of course, you can *change* what's in your work-tree.  Once you do, you can then `git add` files *from* the work-tree, to update the copy in the index.  (If they are entirely new path names, they create new index entries.)

  After changing things in the work-tree and `git add`ing (or `git rm`ing) them all, you run `git commit` to make a *new* commit.  This writes the index out to some tree(s) and writes a commit, and now your work-tree and index and commit all match again.

  Note that `git status` does *two* comparisons:

  1. What's different between the *current commit* the index?
  2. What's different between the index and the work-tree?

  The former are "files staged for commit" and the latter are "files *not* staged for commit".  This is because if you ran `git commit` *now*, whatever is in the index—all its original files from the current commit, except overwritten with all the ones you have `git add`ed—would go into the *new* commit.  But any files you *haven't* `git add`ed *won't* go into the new commit: they're not yet *staged*.  Hence, the index is the staging area.  You `git add` files to copy them from the work-tree, to make them ready to commit.

Now, `.gitignore` files are not *at all* about commits, or even that much about the index.  The issue here is that in a typical work-tree, we wind up with files that are not source files and should not be committed.  If you have such files sitting around in your work-tree, and you run `git status`—which you should do frequently—you will get all kinds of whining from Git about all these *untracked files*.  **But what, exactly, *is* an "untracked file"?**

Git's definition of an untracked file is ridiculously simple (for Git): it's *any file that is not in the index*.  That's it!  A file that is not currently in the index is *untracked*.  Git will complain about it—unless, that is, you list it in a `.gitignore`.  A file that *is* in the index is tracked, and as a tracked file, Git will add it *automatically* if it's changed.  **We'll see `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree` in a moment.**

That's basically most of what `.gitignore` does for you: it shuts Git up about those untracked files.  It has *no* effect on files that *are* tracked.  They are already in the index.  You cannot stop them from being in the index.  You *can*, of course, *remove* them from the index, using `git rm`, which removes them from the index *and* from the work-tree.  This sets things up so that the *next* commit you make will no longer have the files in the snapshot, because that's what the index is for: the *next commit*.

---

<sup>1</sup>A *bare* repository is one with *no* work-tree.  It still has an index, but with no work-tree, there are no files to get out of sync.  This means that it can work well as a server to which users `git push` new commits.  Those new commits won't mess with anyone actively working: there's no work-tree, so there is no place *to* work, so no one is working there and there is nothing to mess up.

You can add *extra* work-trees to a Git repository using the new-in-version-2.5 `git worktree` subcommand.  Each added work-tree comes with its own index.  There's still a "main" work-tree that uses "the" index, but since each added work-tree has its own index, you can mostly think of the two as being tied together.  This breaks down if you get too sneaky with `git --work-tree=`, though: that keeps using the main index, and you can thus get your index out of sync with your main work-tree.

---

#### Assume-unchanged and skip-worktree

These two items are actually special flag bits that you can set on an index entry.  Since they *are* flag bits, you must *have* an index entry for some file path, in order to set them.  They are meant for somewhat different purposes, although they both do the same thing in many cases:

- `--assume-unchanged` tells Git not to bother checking if the work-tree version of a file is newer than the index version.  This is intended for use on systems where "stat" operations are very slow or otherwise undesirable.  But Git might still check anyway, if it has to for some *other* reason.
- `--skip-worktree` tells Git that *even if* the work-tree version is *definitely* newer than the index version, Git should pretend otherwise.  This is sort of a stronger version of "assume unchanged": not only can Git skip checking, it should "close its eyes" and pretend, even if it *does* check.

Both, however, still have the file in the index.  They just let you mess with (i.e., alter) the work-tree version, without that affecting Git's idea of whether the index version needs to be re-loaded out of the work-tree.  **Checkout and merge do not obey, nor even use, these index flag bits.**

#### Checkout writes into the index, and then into the work-tree

We mentioned above that each new `git checkout` makes the index match the new commit.  That continues to be true, even if you have set these flag bits.  But Git tries to be clever and fast, and one of the tricks it uses is this:

- You have a *current* commit, and it's been copied to the index (and then on into the work-tree).
- You are checking out a *new* (newly-to-be-current) commit.  Many of its files are probably exactly the same as in the *old* (currently-current) commit.

If the new commit's copy of `README.txt` is exactly the same as the old one's, why then, there's no need to touch the index version *or* the work-tree version.  The same holds for the other 371,942 unchanged files; only the six *changed* files have to be copied into the index and then on to the work-tree.

If some, or most or even all, of the *unchanged* files have some special flags set in the index, and the work-tree versions are all messed-with, that leaves the work-tree versions all messed-with.  Those changes are conveniently carried through.

But if some of the *changed* files are messed-with ... well, Git *checks:* even with assume-unchanged or skip-worktree, Git looks to see if the files have to be clobbered.  If so, it tells you that your files will be clobbered.  But if they're just *removed* from the work-tree, there's nothing to worry about: there is no precious data; it's safe enough to extract the new files into the index and then on into the work-tree.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>In fact, listing these file names in a `.gitignore` actually makes them *more* clobber-able, in one way: an untracked file that is not ignored makes Git stop and say "hey, I would overwrite or remove this file"; but for an untracked file that *is* ignored, Git feels free to overwrite or remove it.  This is one of the ways listing a file in `.gitignore` makes it more, rather than less, vulnerable to surprise changes, especially when moving from a commit that has or lacks that file, to one that lacks or has it (respectively).

---

#### Merge

When working with `git merge`, the picture gets quite a bit cloudier.  Merges—as done by `git merge`, anyway—come in several varieties, two of which are particularly relevant here:

- A *fast forward* merge is not actually a merge at all; it is really just `git checkout` in disguise (plus a label move, a la `git checkout -B`).
- A *true merge* uses the index in a more complex way.

Without getting into details, we can say that if you *never* make any commits of your own, *and* your "upstream"—the other Git from which you fetch-and-merge (aka "pull")—never "rewrites history", you will always get one of these fast-forward non-merge "merges".  So that puts us right back at the `git checkout` case above.

#### What to do about this

To *really* make sure that some file, or some entire sub-tree, is removed and *stays* removed, you *must* make your own commits.  Ideally, you should make them on your own branch or branches.  You then have easy, complete control of how and when "their work"—the commits you bring in from your upstream repository—will be merged, using a true merge, with your own commits.

To remove the sub-tree and commit this on your own branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

(this creates the new branch at your current commit);

```
git rm -r matlab_stuff
```

(this removes them all from the index and work-tree); and:

```
git commit
```

The last step makes a new commit, on your own new branch you just made.  You have a new commit that has *no* `matlab_stuff` directory-full-of-files in it.  You can now ignore (as in `.gitignore`) any such files if you create them, or not bother to ignore them if you don't create them in the first place.

Note that, in the future, you will eventually do:

```
git fetch
```

and pick up new commits from "them" (whoever they are), and then you will need to *merge* their work with your work:

```
git merge origin/master
```

for instance.

Git will now find the most recent place you were in sync—at this point, it's when you made your own branch—and compare *what you did* with *what they did*.  "What you did" is simple: you removed all those files.  "What they did"—well, that depends on what they did.

If they modified some `matlab_stuff` files, Git will give you a *merge conflict:* "changed in theirs, deleted in ours."  Git does not know what the correct thing is to do here.  *You* do, though: you are ignoring their work here on purpose, so you want to keep the file removed.  If Git has put their file back (which it will), your job is now to re-remove it.  Simply `git rm` it again.  This will tell Git that the correct way to combine their change with your removal is to leave the file removed.  Then you can `git commit` the result, which will create a new commit on your branch, recording that final merge result.

(Note that all of this conflict resolution uses the index.  There are actually *four* slots for each file, of which at most three are ever actually used.  Slot zero is for normal, unconflicted files.  Resolving a conflict involves copying the result to slot zero.  Slots 1, 2, and 3 are used to hold the *merge base*, `--ours`, and `--theirs` versions during a conflicted merge.  Your job, as the person resolving the merge, is to look at these three versions and come up with the correct merged file—or in your case, look at the two versions, base and theirs, and the lack-of-ours, and come up with the correct lack-of-file merge result.)

This is not the most convenient thing in the world, but it is what Git gives you out of the box.  You can, of course, add your own wrapper scripts to automatically remove any merge-conflict `matlab_stuff` files.  That part is up to you.